# Why modal appears and then disappears?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I've made pretty simple modal code with minimum of JS I think. 
When button is pressed, modal appears for a second that page refreshes and modal disappears. 
I've no clue what may be wrong. Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/wj3r2qzu/

```
var modalBtn = document.querySelector("#modal-btn");
var modalBg = document.querySelector(".modal-bg");
var modalClose = document.querySelector(".modal-close");

modalBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
modalBg.classList.add("bg-active");
});

modalClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
modalBg.classList.remove("bg-active");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `type="button"` to your sign up button.

`<button class="primary-btn" type="button" id="modal-btn">Sign Up</button>`

By default, button inside form is of `type="submit"`, so when you click it, the form is being submitted.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8t7efak/)

Answer (score 1):

As Anurag said, that button is by default type="submit", that inside a form will try to redirect, another thing that you can do in your js is prevented the default behavior for that button.

```js
modalBtn.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
 ev.preventDefault();//you can prevent the default action for that button
  modalBg.classList.add("bg-active");
});
```

Hope this can be helpful.